# SSIS OLE DB Source - move cache location

Tags: sql-server, caching, ssis

When SSIS package is run by scheduler on server, the disc C: gets full and computation crashes with error **Failed to retrieve long data for column "Col1"**.

Package has 3 steps:

1. OLE DB Source - Retrieve whole table with binary data - this step fails
2. Script Component - Compute hash of each data
3. OLE DB Destination - Save hash to different table

If I run sql script from 1) in Management Studio SQL Query, it fails with error: **"An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: There is not enough space on the disk."**

**Is it possible to move any caching of this particular package to other disc?
Or to move caching of all packages to other disc?**

By other disc I mean disc, where neither SQL Server is installed, nor SQL Server Data are saved.

Changing Tools > Options: Query Results > SQL Server > General: Default location for saving query results in Management Studio did not help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you go to the 'Data Flow' Tab, right click anywhere not on a task and select properties.
There will be two items

BLOBTempStoragePath

BufferTempStoragePath

you can change the location there.